# How to define function with dependant keyword arguments in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function with 1 positional argument and 2 keyword arguments as:

```
def foo(arg1, kw_arg1='Keyword Argument', kw_arg2='Keyword Argument'):
    print('The arguments are: {}, {}, {}'.format(arg1, kw_arg1, kw_arg2))
```

Now, I want the default value of my second keyword argument, namely `kw_arg2` to depend on `kw_arg1`. To be more precise, I want the value of `kw_arg2` default to `kw_arg1` when it is not passed to the function `foo`.

A function prototype of the requirement would be:

```
def foo(arg1, kw_arg1='Keyword Argument', kw_arg2=kw_arg1):
    print('The arguments are: {}, {}, {}'.format(arg1, kw_arg1, kw_arg2))
```

However, this leads to a `NameError` when run on Python 3.6.0

**Basic Solution**

I figured out a workaround for this by defining my function as:

```
def foo(arg1, kw_arg1='Keyword Argument', kw_arg2=None):
    if kw_arg2 is None:
        kw_arg2 = kw_arg1

    print('The arguments are: {}, {}, {}'.format(arg1, kw_arg1, kw_arg2))
```

However, I find this implementation a bit restrictive in the sense that I am being implicit in stating the relationship between `kw_arg1` and `kw_arg2`. Also, I am losing the ability of setting `kw_arg2` as `None`.

I want to know how can I achieve this through some more explicit workaround.

Comment: You could try using a decorator.

Comment: You can still use `None`. Use a top-level `NODEFAULT = object()` and use that, and check for `NODEFAULT`.

Comment: I think your workaround is essentially fine, why complicate things? As juanpa says, you can use a different sentinel if `None` is a valid input value

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use `**kwargs`, and ask the user to supply `kw_arg2` to the function if required as a keyword argument (i.e. document this!!) .

This has the benefit of not falling apart if the user supplies `None` to `kw_arg2`.

The downside to this approach is that the user **has** to supply `kw_arg2` as a keyword argument, and can't rely on just supplying positional arguments, plus it is a little less obvious what arguments the function takes just by looking at the function definition.

```
def foo(arg1, kw_arg1='Keyword Argument', **kwargs):
    """A function that does foo.

    Args:
        arg1: ...
        kw_arg1: ...
        kw_arg2: Will default to the value of kw_arg1 if no 
                 value is passed to this key word argument.
    """
    if 'kw_arg2' in kwargs:
        kw_arg2 = kwargs['kw_arg2']
    else:
        kw_arg2 = kw_arg1
    print('The arguments are: {}, {}, {}'.format(arg1, kw_arg1, kw_arg2))
```

If you wanted the user to also be able to pass in `kw_arg2` as a positional argument, you could possible try some trickery with *args and **kwargs, but of course this is something you would need to be careful with, and balance up potential misuse vs. benefit:

```
def foo(arg1, kw_arg1='Keyword Argument', *args, **kwargs):
    """A function that does foo."""
    if 'kw_arg2' in kwargs:
        kw_arg2 = kwargs['kw_arg2']
    elif args:
        kw_arg2 = args[0]
    else:
        kw_arg2 = kw_arg1
    print('The arguments are: {}, {}, {}'.format(arg1, kw_arg1, kw_arg2))
```